# How do I create a XAML binding to a member variable?

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm new to XAML and data binding. I want to define a GUI control in `MainWindow.xaml` that gets its data from a member variable in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`. For simplicity's sake I just made a program that displays a counter as well as a button to increment the counter.

Based on [earlier threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325617/i-cant-data-bind-to-a-local-variable-in-wpf-xaml) I've looked up, I came up with the following code:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace XAMLBindingTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int Counter
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(CounterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CounterProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CounterProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("Counter", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Counter = 0;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void incrementCounter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ++Counter;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="XAMLBindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="140" Width="180">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txbCounter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Counter}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnIncrement" Content="Increment" Width="75" Click="incrementCounter"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This example compiles, but the `TextBlock` isn't showing a counter value. How do I wire the `TextBlock` to the `Counter` member in a correct way?

Comment: In your gridview tag put something like: ItemsSource="_testData". This should work because you're using the code behind and that xaml should be able to access the observable collection.

Comment: I get a *Value does not fall within the expected range.* error when I do that.

Comment: Have you tried using a property instead of a member variable?

Comment: I tried it, but it seems to produce the same error.

Comment: If you create sample GridApp in visual studio, you will see the binding syntax and design time binding. I can not see how you are binding data with GridView here.

Comment: I haven't bound any data yet, that's the thing. But I will take a look at the `GridApp` sample.

Comment: Note from the OP: the above comments apply to an [earlier revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13471705/3) of my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding a "Name" to your window and binding using "ElementName"

```
<Window x:Class="XAMLBindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txbCounter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=Counter}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnIncrement" Content="Increment" Width="75" Click="incrementCounter"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly:

```
ItemSource="{Binding Path=TestData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type common:LayoutAwarePage}}}"
```

`TestData` is property of type `ObservableCollection` declared in .xaml.cs file. `ItemSource` - is a example property you want bind to.

UPD2:

```
<ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding Path=TestData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type common:LayoutAwarePage}}}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Did you mean `ItemsSource`? In that case, I got [these errors](http://i.imgur.com/7Ft83.png).

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/n2GtB.png) are my member variables and properties and [here](http://i.imgur.com/MilUp.png) are the errors I get when I paste your suggestion verbatim as a new attribute on `GridView`.

Comment: ItemSource should be a UI control`s property. For example:
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding Path=TestData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type common:LayoutAwarePage}}}"/>

Comment: Am I doing it wrong? `<GridView x:Name="grvTasks" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TaskGroupTemplate}" ItemSource="{Binding Path=TestData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type common:LayoutAwarePage}}}" />`

Comment: You should also declare columns if you want use GridView. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752213.aspx for more information. 
In your case it will be something like
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
                          "{Binding Path=.}" 
                      Header="Header" Width="100"/>

Comment: I may have chosen the wrong type of control then. I want to visualize a list of objects in a grid-like fashion (but not using a table like the MSDN doc suggests), so I might need a `ListView` instead. How would I do this in a `ListView`?

Comment: This generates two errors: *The member "ItemSource" is not recognized or is not accessible* and *The property 'ItemSource' was not found in type 'ItemsControl'*. When I change *ItemSource* to *ItemsSource* I [also get errors](http://i.imgur.com/EO00e.png).