# Windows Phone 8 Checkbox Binding with Public Property

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to bind my checkbox to a public boolean property, but I could not get it work.

Am I missing something?

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <CheckBox Name="CheckBox2" IsChecked="{Binding CheckBoxState}">
        </CheckBox>   </Grid>
```

code behind:

```
  public const string NamePropertyName = "CheckBoxState";
    private bool _checkboxstate = true;

    public bool CheckBoxState
    {
        get { return _checkboxstate; }
        set
        {
            if (_checkboxstate == value) return;
            _checkboxstate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(NamePropertyName);
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }



    void appBarButtonSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // HERE IT SHOULD TOGGLE STATE BUT IT DOES NOT!
        CheckBoxState = !CheckBoxState;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer was hidden seven layer below the surface. I was literally checking every single wpf binding question to reach to answer and eventually I found it! I started to think it is WP8 problem more than WPF.

So I had to bind datacontext of my window like

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13337258/929902)

I gotta do more reading on wpf binding :)